# PHP email header subject issue

Tags: php, forms

I've been trying to add a subject line to my contact form and I just can't get it to work.
There must be something missing but I just can't figure it out.
When the email arrives I can see the Name and the email of the user but I can't get the subject.

I believe it's something wrong with my PHP script:

```
<?php
 $names = $_POST['names'];
 $email = $_POST['email_address'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $comment = $_POST['comment'];
 $to ='my-email@hotmail.com';

 $message = "";
 $message .= "Name: " . htmlspecialchars($names, ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
 $message .= "Email: " . htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
 $message .= "Subject: " . htmlspecialchars($subject, ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";

 $message .= "Comment: " . htmlspecialchars($comment, ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
 $lowmsg = strtolower($message);

 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: \"" . $names . "\" <" . $email . ">\r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";
 $message = utf8_decode($message);  mail($to, "Note from the Contact Form", $message, $headers);

 if ($message){
   echo 'sent';
 }else{
    echo 'failed';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Does `$_POST['subject']` exist? Just to be clear, you want the message to look like Name: John\n Email: john@john.com\n Subject: My Subject (this is not working) You do see the subject you give to the mail function as the subject of the e-mail itself?

Comment: Shouldn't the Subject be part of the headers rather than the msg?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to headers injection. See http://security.stackexchange.com/a/1111

Comment: Which subject are you talking about? The `Subject:` line in the body of the message, or the `Notes from the Contact Form` subject in the `mail()` function?